# mbstring will not add to my php on windows 10

Tags: php, mbstring

I need mbstring for something I'm doing.  I've followed all the php.ini change directions to enable it and still when I do "php -m" the module is not there.

1. The php_mbstring.dll file is in the ext folder
2. I have two php.ini files, one for dev and prod
3. in both I've remove the semi colon and enabled "extension = php_mbstring.dll"
4. Also in both I've un commented all the settings under [mbstring]

Restarted my computer and nothing?  Is there a way to add it in windows command like they have in linux with "sudo apt-get mbstring"?

Also note my ini files just had ";extension=mbstring"  which I first uncommented in the ini's but that did not work so I tried adding the whole "extension = php_mbstring.dll" and as noted above this did not work.

Why??

Comment: did you see that  
note : First, you need to install that specific extension, i.e. place its DLL file "php-mbstring.dll" into the "/php/ext/" directory if it is not already present there. When you do that, make sure you have the correct build of DLL file. 32-bit, thread-safe PHP binary, built using VC9 for example, would only work with DLL files built using exact same tools and configuration: 32-bit, using VC9, with thread-safety turned on. And of course PHP API version also needs to match. If it doesn’t, once you restart the web server, you will receive ’Error 500 - Server error’ message.

Comment: Yes as per my #1 on the list, the php_mbstring.dll file did come with the php installation.  This is php 8.2.3

Comment: thing is I don't have a web server.  It's kind of strange I'm running vagrant but in order to do this migration on codeigniter 4 I need php on my main machine

Comment: The vagrant linux box has mbstring but not my windows install

Comment: and this extention is enabled ? extension_dir = "path\php\ext"

Comment: I don't have xampp,  that's for mac right?  I have Mamp, but I don't know if I need mamp to have php work correctly right?  that's just a development stack

Comment: no , mamp or xampp just for ensure that the php work correctly if you're not using the server

Comment: if you can see this https://sebhastian.com/mbstring-missing-php/ maybe can help you

Comment: Thanks,  it actually worked when I ssh'ed into my vagrant box.  So that's a work around. Still would be nice to do from my main terminal but for now I have a work around.  I apricate your help and will read this article.

Answer (score -1):

php 8.2.3? May be depricated?

Replacing the Mbstring-provided conversion functions with the built-in dedicated functions avoids the deprecation notice, with the added benefit of the replacing functions being built-in to PHP core itself, without having to require the Mbstring extension. - https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mbstring-qprint-base64-uuencode-html-entities-deprecated#base64

Comment: Yea well my CodeIgniter 4 claims to need mbstring to use php spark.  So I guess at this point since 8.2 is trying to depreciate it, I should uninstall it and install an older version.